# SAP Cloud SDK access Extension Suite Data/Lists of Destinations available/Groups

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I was wondering if they are any possibility with the sap cloud SDK for java to consume some API used by the cockpit?

For example:

- To get all services they are the URL below

  ```
  https://account.hana.ondemand.com/ajax/getServices/<subaccount>?globalAccountId=<globalaccountid>
  ```
- To get all html5 applications they are the URL below:

  ```
  https://account.hana.ondemand.com/ajax/getHtml5Applications/<subaccount>
  ```
- Last example for destinations:

  ```
  https://account.hana.ondemand.com/ajax/destinationsdispatcher/tenant/get/<subaccount>
  ```

So I would like to consume this service throw my java application, is it possible ?
Or does any class/library available in the com.sap.cloud SDK that do the jobs?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by API used by cockpit, is it some kind of a REST API available in API Business Hub: https://api.sap.com/ ?

Comment: If you had a look in the cockpit they are some ajax call like /ajax/getHtml5Applications/<subaccount> that return a JSON so has this call is not available under any API Business Hub I would like to find a way to consume this API from my java application

Comment: If we manage to find the API spec associated with these REST calls, we can use the OpenAPI generator of the SAP Cloud SDK to generate a client to conveniently consume this API: https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/rest/generate-rest-client

Let me try to find the associated specification.

Comment: Agree with you but this need to use the API Management and configure it also so even I do that I'm not sure I will be able to get all I need

Comment: ​Hello,
Find something interesting looking this: https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/d31bdd53b57744fcb9eb9c93556cfddf.html
We can access Destination in the SAP BTP throw JNDI lookup does any other JNDI available ?

Answer (score 0):

To access the apps & services in a Cloud Foundry account via REST please refer to the [API documentation of Cloud Foundry](http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.109.0/index.html).

You can also do the same via the [Cloud Foundry CLI](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/install-go-cli.html).

The Destinations you mention are special in the sense that they are not coming from Cloud Foundry directly but belong to a separate, dedicated BTP service which is called [Destination Service](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/eeb0ec2318fb4dda87830a09ac7a02fa.html).

To access Destinations from the BTP Destination Service you can use the SAP Cloud SDK for [Java](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/connectivity/sdk-connectivity-destination-service#accessing-destinations) or [JavaScript](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/js/features/connectivity/destination).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but actually what I have done is to declare a new destination to the cockpit 
URL: https://cockpit.eu10.hana.ondemand.com
Basic Authentication provided access Internet

From a web application I have put in the neo-app.json file the destination previously created and made the call excalty with /ajax/<service_to_call> but I'm getting an error type
403 Unauthorized to access this page you can check for example if you have a SAP BTP Neo account with the url below https://cockpit.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/ajax/getAllGlobalAccounts

Comment: Oh okay you are running on NEO and not on Cloud Foundry. In that case I'd recommend to check [this resource](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b865ed651e414196b39f8922db2122c7/Cloud/en-US/30a5e88495b349e4b073313897342189.html) and this [API documentation](https://api.sap.com/api/SAP_CP_Neo_Connectivity_Destination/resource).

Comment: I'd recommend migrating to CF from Neo soon. You'll have a much richer and better-supported ecosystem.